# Template class and Friend template function

Tags: c++, templates

C++ Primer: Template and Functioins

```
template <typename>
class BlobPtr;

template <typename>
class Blob;

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
template <typename T>
class Blob
{
    friend class BlobPtr<T>;
    friend bool operator==<T>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
};
```

Then:

```
Blob<char> ca;
Blob<int> ia;
```

> The members of `BlobPtr<char>` may access the nonpublic parts of ca (or any
>   other Blob object), but ca has no special access to ia (or any other
>   Blob) or to any other instantiation of Blob.

**Question**:
I'd like to test the code. How can I access the nonpublic parts of **ia** with ca? To clarify, I know it's not possible, but I'd like to test the code to see the error.

Comment: Set up a private member of `Blob` and a member function which tries to access the private member of another specialisation of `Blob`.    (e.g. `Blob<char>::foo()` tries to access the private member of a `Blob<int>` - or vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add `template` before using `friend`.

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Blob
{
    template<typename T1>
    friend class Blob;

public:
    template<typename T1>
    bool operator==(const Blob<T1>& other)
    {
        return i == other.i;
    }
private:
    T i;
};

Blob<int> i;
Blob<char> j;

int main()
{
    i == j;
}
```

Adding template makes every `Blob<T>` class into a friend class of each other. So, every member function of `Blob<int>` can access to private members of `Blob<char>` and vice versa.